# Create .db file in SD-CARD after checking its existence in blackberry?

Tags: file, blackberry, sd-card, delete-file

I am working to create a db file in my application. Now I want to create the .db file on application installation just one time. 
When I open the app, it just check for the existence of the file.

How can we check for a .db file in sdcard and if it exists before installation than to delete the file.

Comment: Did you check the sample application, `SQLiteDemo` provided by RIM with Eclipse Plugin for BlackBerry, JRE 6.0? On line 126 of that application, it checks existence of the file, and is it blank. If the file exists and blank then it creates a new database file. You need to work on that portion to find out the fact that if the database file created by current version of your application, or by other application / old version of your application.

Comment: To accomplish this you can use persistent data store utility of the BlackBerry API. When you create a new database file, you can also store some information which can be later used to determine that current version of your application created the database file. And if you found that the database file created by others, then just delete the file using `FileConnection.delete()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if file exists or not using following code

```
 FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/foldername/" + "databasename.db");

    boolean result=fileConnection.exists(); 

  if(result)
  {
     //database available
  }else{
       //database not available
  }
```

and next you want to check this when application first time instalation using

```
 CodeModuleListener listner=new CodeModuleListener() {

            public void modulesDeleted(String[] moduleNames) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void modulesAdded(int[] handles) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //here you can check if database available or not if available then delete 
                try{
                    URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/foldername/" + "database_name.db"); 
                    DatabaseFactory.delete(myURI);  
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

            }

            public void moduleDeletionsPending(String[] moduleNames) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        CodeModuleManager.addListener(this.getApplication(), listner);
```

Comment: implemented this but it is not working, the modulesAdded or moduleDeleted or moduleDeletionsPending methods are not hitting the breakpoints.:(